# PowerShell Script to Generate Large Volume (in millions) 'n' digits Unique Number

Tags: powershell, unique-id

I am trying to write a powershell script to generate about 9 million unique number. Is there any efficient way to do that?

### As of now My script is, But it is generating duplicate values

```
$start = [long] $startNumber
$end = [long] $endNumber
$random = New-Object System.Random
$number = @()

while ($start -lt $end){

$customerObject = new-object PSObject

    $randomnumber = $random.Next(100000000,999999999)
    while ($number -contains $randomnumber) {
            $randomnumber = $random.Next(100000000,999999999)
     }
    $number += $randomnumber
    [long] $uniqueId = 2000000000 +[long] $randomnumber;



$customerObject | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name CUSTOMERID -Value $uniqueId 

$start++
$resultsarray += $customerObject

}
```

---

Comment: `$endNumber` and `$startNumber` are both null from what you have shown us here. Where to those get populated from?

Comment: @Matt From his description, the difference between them would be 9 mio. in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would maintain a separate [`HashSet<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep track of the distinct values already generated.

A `HashSet` doesn't preserve insertion order but is crazy-fast to perform lookups against, unlike a regular array in which lookup-performance will become quite sluggish after a while (which you've probably already seen yourself).

Secondly, avoid `+=` at any cost. PowerShell arrays resize themselves by recreating and copying the underlying array to a slighter larger array. This constant resizing is going to hurt performance as well.

You can rely on the pipeline alone by simply "dropping" your variables on a line and assign the output from the entire `while` loop to a variable that will then contain your random(ly ordered) sequence:

```
$random = New-Object System.Random
$set = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]'

$limit = $endNumber - $startNumber

$sequence = while($set.Count -lt $limit)
{
    # Generate random number
    $n = $random.Next(100000000,999999999)

    # Re-generate until a distinct value is produced
    while($set.Contains($n)){
        $n = $random.Next(100000000,999999999)
    }

    # Add value to set
    [void]$set.Add($n)

    # Let value "bubble up" to the variable
    $n
}
```

Comment: Well... I have nothing to do here now. You said it all. Down with `+=`

Comment: @Matt Amen, brother! Already at 20000 values, [`+=` is 120 times slower](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/f0b65672c88c6458ed6eed226d1edcee), 125ms v 14.9s on my machine

Comment: Is it really that important to optimize this ? How much do you generate 9M unique numbers so that this will come into effect ? Nice ideas @MathiasR.Jessen anyway.

Comment: @majkinetor you could argue that "just once" is enough, the additional memory allocation and execution time is orders of magnitudes slower with `+=` and `-contains`, since it gets worse and worse with the size. I tried generating a 9M sequence with the approach in my answer, took 45 seconds on my old laptop. Tried it again with OPs approach and had to Ctrl+C the darn thing after 12-13 minutes

Comment: I am not sure I follow you @MathiasR.Jessen. 12 minute or 12 hours is irrelevant if you do it only once. Its not like you have to sit there and direct computer how to execute each line. This is clearly premature optimization which costs time. Good as learning exercise tho and perhaps for interview questions @ booking :)

Comment: @majkinetor I assume OP asks this question because he's already concluded that his approach is way too inefficient ("Is there any efficient way to do that?"). The actual use case he presents took me 10 minutes to optimize (premature or not) - i'd consider it justified. Having to wait (as a human) is also not the primary gain here. In the age of cloud computing I'd argue that an operation using 12 CPU cycles is more attractive than one that takes 12000 CPU cycles to do the same thing.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Well, remember this idea for next interview then :)

Comment: Optimization is actually incredibly important when you scale up your functions in big programs or entire systems. Planting the seed of knowledge that optimization is important could very well mean a future server application or function runs faster and better than a slower, more resource-heavy method. Same practice applies to any OOP language... namely java and c# for examples. Definitely not just for interview questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helped me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Related to your duplicate values: why don't you just generate some more and then pipe to `| sort -unique` ? Then check the length of resulting array and generate some more if needed.

As for efficiency, I guess you can't get it faster in Posh, but you could create C# implementation which is going to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion. Will try it in C#.

Comment: No, the answer from mathias is definitely good. Also sorting will double the time again and since you are hunting time it will not do.